# Is it possible to move a 3D object using the position of hand obtained from camera UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, unity-components

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I want to create a unity program where I'm able to provide a 3D model of the hand on the screen based on the input from a camera. I'm using HandPoseBarracuda for detecting and obtaining the position of the hand in real-time.
Is there any way to access the skeletal points of the rigged model through the C# code in Unity?

How can I map the position to the rigged model?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHa3X.png

Comment: I haven’t used it myself but if you already have HandPoseBarracuda working with UnityBarracuda in Unity I would have thought you could just attach it to whatever points they use for their hand demo? What is their hand setup? Their video on GitHub shows no actual hand model but just a bunch of spheres at the articulation points.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the code now. joint balls and bones are updated in the Animator game object's attached script HandAnimator.cs in LateUpdate() function.

you can simply get a list of all ball positions in the loop like this.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
**using System.Collections.Generic;**

namespace MediaPipe.HandPose
{

    public sealed class HandAnimator : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Editable attributes

        [SerializeField] WebcamInput _webcam = null;
        [SerializeField] ResourceSet _resources = null;
        [SerializeField] bool _useAsyncReadback = true;
        [Space]
        [SerializeField] Mesh _jointMesh = null;
        [SerializeField] Mesh _boneMesh = null;
        [Space]
        [SerializeField] Material _jointMaterial = null;
        [SerializeField] Material _boneMaterial = null;
        [Space]
        [SerializeField] RawImage _monitorUI = null;

        public List<Vector3> positions;

        #endregion

        #region Private members

        HandPipeline _pipeline;

        static readonly (int, int)[] BonePairs =
        {
        (0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4),     // Thumb
        (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8),                     // Index finger
        (9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12),                // Middle finger
        (13, 14), (14, 15), (15, 16),               // Ring finger
        (17, 18), (18, 19), (19, 20),               // Pinky
        (0, 17), (2, 5), (5, 9), (9, 13), (13, 17)  // Palm
    };

        Matrix4x4 CalculateJointXform(Vector3 pos)
          => Matrix4x4.TRS(pos, Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one * 0.07f);

        Matrix4x4 CalculateBoneXform(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)
        {
            var length = Vector3.Distance(p1, p2) / 2;
            var radius = 0.03f;

            var center = (p1 + p2) / 2;
            var rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, p2 - p1);
            var scale = new Vector3(radius, length, radius);

            return Matrix4x4.TRS(center, rotation, scale);
        }

        #endregion

        #region MonoBehaviour implementation

        void Start()
          => _pipeline = new HandPipeline(_resources);

        void OnDestroy()
          => _pipeline.Dispose();

        void LateUpdate()
        {
            // Feed the input image to the Hand pose pipeline.
            _pipeline.UseAsyncReadback = _useAsyncReadback;
            _pipeline.ProcessImage(_webcam.Texture);

            var layer = gameObject.layer;

            **positions = new List<Vector3>();**
            // Joint balls
        for (var i = 0; i < HandPipeline.KeyPointCount; i++)
            {
                **Vector3 pos = _pipeline.GetKeyPoint(i);
                var xform = CalculateJointXform(pos);
                Graphics.DrawMesh(_jointMesh, xform, _jointMaterial, layer);
                positions.Add(pos);**
            }

            // Bones
            foreach (var pair in BonePairs)
            {
                var p1 = _pipeline.GetKeyPoint(pair.Item1);
                var p2 = _pipeline.GetKeyPoint(pair.Item2);
                var xform = CalculateBoneXform(p1, p2);
                Graphics.DrawMesh(_boneMesh, xform, _boneMaterial, layer);
            }

            // UI update
            _monitorUI.texture = _webcam.Texture;
        }

        #endregion
    }

} // namespace MediaPipe.HandPose
```

[image: after changing your code you can see the list of all balls positions in the inspector like this image]

Finally select each position you want in the list and update your special object's position with the selected position.